# Array adapter display only last element of the array.How to get all the value

Tags: android

i am having the following code for display the contacts in my application. i am having the problem to display the contacts. my array(from) get only one value from database but in database many values are there. How to get the all values from database.

mydatabasecode:

```
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return contactList;
}
```

GetvalueFromDb code:

```
 List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
    for (Contact cn : contacts) {
        from = new String[] { cn.getName()};
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+Arrays.toString(from), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
note = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.contact_edit,from);
        lv.setAdapter(note);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are making `from` only a single string, not a string array to apply to the array adapter. Try the following:

```
List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
ArrayList<String> from = new ArrayList<String>;
for (Contact cn : contacts) {
    from.add(cn.getName());
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+Arrays.toString(from), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
note = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.contact_edit, from);
    lv.setAdapter(note);
```

Answer (score 1):

because your initializing `from  array` in loop and last time when loop runs you gets that last single value

you can try

```
List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
from = new String[contacts.size()];
int i=0;
for (Contact cn : contacts) {
from[i]=cn.getName();
i++;             
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+Arrays.toString(from), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```